# Проблема с ComboBox MaterialDesign WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design, combobox

Почему такое происходит с ComboBox?

```cs
ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox
{
   Margin = new Thickness(22, 7, 5, 0),
   VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
   HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
   VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
   Height = 45,
   Style = (Style)FindResource("MaterialDesignFloatingHintComboBox")
};
comboBox.SetValue(HintAssist.HintProperty, Column);
comboBox.ItemsSource = db.Query<string>($"SELECT [{Columnn}] FROM [{Table}]").ToList();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118916/discussion-on-question-by-nastia---combobox-materialdesign-wpf).